# How to view pushed and partition filters in Spark 3

Tags: apache-spark

How can you view the partition filters and pushed filters in Spark 3 (3.0.0-preview2)?

The `explain` method outputted detail like this in Spark 2:

```
== Physical Plan ==
Project [first_name#12, last_name#13, country#14]
+- Filter (((isnotnull(country#14) && isnotnull(first_name#12)) && (country#14 = Russia)) && StartsWith(first_name#12, M))
   +- FileScan csv [first_name#12,last_name#13,country#14]
        Batched: false,
        Format: CSV,
        Location: InMemoryFileIndex[file:/Users/powers/Documents/tmp/blog_data/people.csv],
        PartitionFilters: [],
        PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(country), IsNotNull(first_name), EqualTo(country,Russia), StringStartsWith(first_name,M)],
        ReadSchema: struct
```

This would easily let you identify the PartitionFilters and PushedFilters.

In Spark 3, the explain is a lot less, even when the `extended` argument is set:

```
val path = new java.io.File("./src/test/resources/person_data.csv").getCanonicalPath
val df = spark.read.option("header", "true").csv(path)
df
  .filter(col("person_country") === "Cuba")
  .explain("extended")
```

Here's the output:

```
== Parsed Logical Plan ==
'Filter ('person_country = Cuba)
+- RelationV2[person_name#115, person_country#116] csv file:/Users/matthewpowers/Documents/code/my_apps/mungingdata/spark3/src/test/resources/person_data.csv

== Analyzed Logical Plan ==Only 18s
person_name: string, person_country: string
Filter (person_country#116 = Cuba)
+- RelationV2[person_name#115, person_country#116] csv file:/Users/matthewpowers/Documents/code/my_apps/mungingdata/spark3/src/test/resources/person_data.csv

== Optimized Logical Plan ==
Filter (isnotnull(person_country#116) AND (person_country#116 = Cuba))
+- RelationV2[person_name#115, person_country#116] csv file:/Users/matthewpowers/Documents/code/my_apps/mungingdata/spark3/src/test/resources/person_data.csv

== Physical Plan ==
*(1) Project [person_name#115, person_country#116]
+- *(1) Filter (isnotnull(person_country#116) AND (person_country#116 = Cuba))
   +- BatchScan[person_name#115, person_country#116] CSVScan Location: InMemoryFileIndex[file:/Users/matthewpowers/Documents/code/my_apps/mungingdata/spark3/src/test/re..., ReadSchema: struct<person_name:string,person_country:string>
```

Is there any way to see the partition filters and pushed filters in Spark 3?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like it was a bug that was fixed towards the end of April. The JIRA for the predicate pushdown is [SPARK-30475](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-30475) and for the partition pushdown is [SPARK-30428](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-30428).

Can you check if your version of Spark has this fix included in it?

Comment: I am using 3.0.0-preview2, the latest version at the moment.

Comment: That version was released on Dec 2019. The latest preview release is Spark 3.0. 0-preview2, published on Dec 23, 2019. These fixes were done later, I believe a version is coming out at the end of May in which these issues will be fixed.